# 2 wp querys clashing with pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have been trying to display a featured post and also the latest posts on the same page but when I go to use pagination, it shows /page/2 in the permalink but it shows the same posts as page 1. I have a feeling the querys are conflicting! How do I fix this please? Code below

```
     <?php query_posts( array( 
     'post_type' => array('event-', 'videos', 'videos-', 'audio', 'audio-'), 
     'posts_per_page'  => 1,
     'meta_key'        => '_featured',
     'meta_value'      => 'yes'


      )); 
     ?>

      <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="potdpostcon">

            <div class="featuredimgpotd">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div class="featuredpostimgzoom"></div><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'featured-post-home' ); ?></a>
            </div>

            <div class="featuredbasepotd">

                <div class="desclrgexcon"><span class="postexplrg"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="postexplrg"><?php the_titlesmall('', '...', true, '82') ?></a></span></div>
                <div class="goiconlargecon"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="fade"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/goicon_lrg.png" /></a>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

2nd wp query:

```
<?php

  $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

  $args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'videos', 'videos-', 'audio-', 'event-'),
    'showposts' => 80,
    'paged' => $paged
  );

  $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>


      <?php
if( $current_date != get_the_date('d-m-Y') ){
    echo '<div class="datetitle100spc"><div class="datetitleconspc"></div></div><div class="datetitle100"><div class="datetitlecon"><span class="dateheadertitle">'.get_the_date('l dS / M Y').'</span></div></div>';
    $current_date = get_the_date('d-m-Y');
}
?>


<div class="postmainbase">
<div class="postexcon">
                    <div class="featuredimgexcon"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div class="postcategoryex"><div class="postcategorytitle"><span class="catexsmall"><?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?></span></div></div><div class="featuredimgzoom"></div><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'home-posts' ); ?></a></div>
                    <div class="sepexcon"></div>
                    <div class="descexcon"><span class="postexp"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="postexp"><?php the_titlesmall('', '...', true, '92') ?></a></span></div>
                    <div class="goexcon"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="fade"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/goicon.png" /></a></div>
                </div>
</div>






            <?php endwhile; ?>

  <div class="paginationdiv">
<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
  </div>

     <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm feeling a post data reset issue here, not sure, can someone confirm?

Comment: yeah.. you should reset the wp_query after the first query. Read more over here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks, works ok on a normal page but not index page with pagination.. If i click onto page 2 it shows it in the url but doesnt move pages.. any suggestions? THanks